# quoting strings in Java

Tags: java, string

Does anyone know of a library function to escape and surround a string value of an object with quotes unless it is null?

For example, the function should process:

- `"hello"` as `"\"hello\""`
- `null` as `"null"`
- `Long.valueOf(2L)` as `"\"2\""`
- `""` as `"\"\""`
- `"I\'m \"quoted\""` as `"\"I\\\'m \\\"quoted\\\""`

Clearly this is trivial to implement in Java, but I'm looking for a function in an existing library (e.g. JDK, Commons Lang, Spring ...) I'd be surprised if this hasn't been done before.

For reference, this is for converting objects to JavaScript strings.

Comment: "_function to surround a string value of an object with quotes unless it is null_" then why should `null` become `"null"`?

Comment: It looks like a 1 line method doesn't it? `return arg == null? return "null" : return "\"" + String.valueOf(arg) + "\"";`?

Comment: Let me ask you: By any reason, are you building SQL Strings? It is also good to combine with StringEscapeUtils - Either way, using Parameters in JDBC is your friend, really (and I'm called "Little Bobby Tables") :)

Comment: Yes, it's a trivial method, so I'd be surprised if it has not been implemented before.

Comment: No, this is not for SQL strings, but you're quite right- I do need to escape as well. I'll adjust the question accordingly.

Comment: 2L is not a string, if it is "2L" it should be "\"2L\""

Comment: indeed, 2L is intentionally not a string. It is an example to demonstrate that it should work for arbitrary objects. Perhaps I should have used `Long.valueOf(2L)` as a more explicit example.

Comment: btw, if you want to arbitrarily map into a JavaScript Type System (JSON semantics, perhaps), I'd recommend you look at Jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the Quoting, really. If you want to write Java to JS, use Jackson:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class Teste {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        printAsJs(null);
        printAsJs(5L);
        printAsJs("Hello!");
        printAsJs(new Date());
    }

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void printAsJs(Object o) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(o));
    }

}
```

If you need extra handlers to format as JS, extend ObjectMapper with your desired needs

Thank you come again

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own using StringUtils.

```
import static org.apache.commongs.lang.StringUtils.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.*;

public void quote(String x) {
  return escapeJavaScript(defaultString(x, "null").replaceFirst("^(.*)$", "\"$1\"")));
}
```

Comment: But `StringEscapeUtils` won't do what OP is looking for...

Comment: Actually, he now needs StringEscapeUtils :)

Comment: further:String.valueof(o) asumes that the object has a valid toString() method, otherwise it returns unwanted results

Comment: The input was a String, right? If you want something better, write your own framework ffs :)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are

- Surround output with quotes
- Escape quotes
- Handle `null` different (no surrounding quotes)

I don't know any library method fulfilling your requirements.

Anyway, it can be implemented with a one line method:

```
public static String quoteAndEscape(Object o) {
    return o == null ? "null" : "\"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(String.valueOf(o)) + "\"";
}
```

Comment: Nearly. This doesn't handle the null, but that's easy enough to fix. Is there a library function that already does this?

Comment: @Kkkev what do you mean doesn't handle `null`? If you pass `null`, you'll get `"null"` just like you specified in your expample.

Comment: this returns `"\"null\""` for `null`.

Comment: I misunderstood your example, see my edit.